# Typescript seeing property as undefined, when it is defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Typescript keeps complaining and throwing the error,

```
Property 'tableData' is missing in type '{ children?: ReactNode; }' but required in type '{ tableData: TableData; }'
```

Here is my code:

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';

interface TableData  {
  someField: string;
  anotherField?: string;
  someFunction?: Function;
}

const Table: FC = ({
  tableData: {
    someField,
    anotherField,
    someFunction
  }
}: {
  tableData: TableData;
}) => {
  // ...
};

Table.defaultProps = {
  tableData: {
    someField: 'field1',
    anotherField: 'field2',
    someFunction: () =>
      console.log('Some function')
  }
};
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Pass the prop types to the generic component type: `FC<{ tableData: TableData }>`.

Comment: That did the trick, can you please make it into an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Following the [definition](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react/index.d.ts#L518-L524) of `FunctionComponent` it's a generic type which expects props to be provided as a first parameter, otherwise defaults to empty object which later gets combined with `children` prop so you will end up with `children` prop only.

To fix it you just need to pass definition to `FC`:

```js
import React, { FC } from 'react';

interface TableData  {
  someField: string;
  anotherField?: string;
  someFunction?: Function;
}

interface Props {
  tableData: TableData
}

const Table: FC<Props> = ({
  tableData: {
    someField,
    anotherField,
    someFunction
  }
}) => {
  // ...
};
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=28&pc=3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwnAL5wBmUEIcA5FKhrQNwCwAUB8AHYxJTl0SOABUUAIwA2SACIoYKOLg5KAztST5gSSQBMAXHFUwoPAOZt2SlNwgwAFvy07dAfkPHT3CyqMb8AK7cGMAQ3O4EQSFhliQcXLz8gmjCAApUYKrKVnAKUrLyKIZi+XIKHHGc7GhhxqIS0oZEADzpEJkAfHAAvHAAFDi+edJlRdlKav7aepi+1rYOTtO6szmTIJpRMKHcvpUkAJQ9XYM5APRncAB0NxXMQA)